# Remove inherited permissions with SetACL

Tags: windows, permissions, acl, icacls

I'm using SetACL as an alternative to icacls to process objects' DACL SACL and ownership.

After reading the documentation, I see that the `clear` parameter clears the ACL of any non-inherited ACEs, however I can't find a way to do the same with inherited ACEs.

I can do this with icacls by using `/inheritance:r`

Is there a way to do the same with SetACL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, what I need is in the documentation after all.

You don't remove inherited permissions, you protect child objects from inheritance from parent objects with the action parameter `setprot` like:

```
-actn setprot -op “dacl:p_nc;sacl:p_nc“
```